LINQ query is too slow
I am working on a middle size web application that handles projects, invoices etc.
I struggle to optimize my filter query for a list of projects whenever I filter by subject's substring. It sometimes searches for up to one whole minute - and the DTU in my azure app sky rockets to 100 %.
This is the LINQ Query:

if (!Filter.Client.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    var searchedTerm = Filter.Client;
    query = query.Where(p =>
                            p.AddressBookLinkage
                                .Any(linkage => (linkage.MainContactId == null
                                ? linkage.MainSubject.Name
                                : linkage.MainContact.Name).Contains(searchedTerm)));
    var sqlQuery = query.ToList();
}

AddressBookLinkage holds the IDs of either the subject or contact ID. Each project contains exactly one of them, the other being null.
This is the generated SQL of the subquery that handles the filter on this column
    SELECT 1
    FROM [AddressBookProjectLinkages] AS [a]
    LEFT JOIN [Subjects] AS [s] ON [a].[MainSubjectId] = [s].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [Contacts] AS [c] ON [a].[MainContactId] = [c].[Id]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [a].[ProjectId]) AND ((@__searchedTerm_2 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__searchedTerm_2, CASE
        WHEN [a].[MainContactId] IS NULL THEN [s].[Name]
        ELSE [c].[Name]
    END) > 0)))
ORDER BY [p].[Id]

I think it is important to mention that for some reason, this filter is running in my local environment much smoother than on the production (with the production data). The web app including the SQL server is running on Azure services. However, I can see that such a significant performance difference only happens on this filter.
Another question that arises is whether my Azure SQL server plan is enough. I use the Standard tier with 10 DTUs. Only around 275 MB of DB space is used.

I set up an index on Name of both Subject and Contact, only to realize that the index is probably ignored once I use SQL CHARINDEX or LIKE conditions.
I implemented Full text search on my database and set the index on those two columns, but then I figured out that FTS is not used for substring search.


When you have the generated SQL then throw it in the SQL Server Profiler to see where  potential for optimization is.

The Profiler doesn't optimize queries. The problem is the query itself though, not LINQ. No index can be used to search in the middle of a text field so this query will always have to scan the entire table to find matches.

How many DTUs is your DB? Before we dig too much into X,Y and Z I'd like to make sure you're not running on eg a free 5 DTU dev grade instance

What is this code searching for? FTS does search for words in a string. It doesn't search for partial word matches. If you want to get Banana when searching for ana you'll have to use specialized solutions. SQL Server doesn't have any such features. PostgreSQL does, through trigram indexes. Otherwise you'll have to look at search products like Elastic

Something is definitly wrong. This: "AND ((@__searchedTerm_2 LIKE N'') OR " should be evaluated in the code and different SQL should be sent to server if it was empty string.

Almost all applications use prefix search, ie LIKE 'ban%' or in LINQ, customer.Name.StartsWith(...) because that can be accelerated by normal indexes. The database converts that to a range search eg name >='ban' and name <'bao'

@flackoverstow I just added that information into the post. Those three tables have no more than 1500 records each.

@ThomasKoelle the query is very convoluted, trying to "mix" two fields and a substring search. EF has to come up with a query that handles possible NULL fields and still produce the same result as the query. The logic of the query is wrong, whether it's the substring search or the attempt to mix fields

@user27910466 we all explained what's wrong with the query. This can't be fixed. linkage.MainContactId == null?: always produces bad queries, it's not LINQ's fault. LIKE '%ana%' always has to search the entire table.

Why not change the query to Any(linkage=> linkage.MainSubject.Name.StartsWith(term) || linkage.MainContact.Name.StartsWith(term))? Is substring search important enough to pay for Azure Search and modify the application code? Or switch to PostgreSQL and trigrams ?

using pure SQL you can't fix that with SQL. I already explained why. It doesn't matter if you have few users, you're forcing your company to pay for extra DTUs. Does the substring search matter to them?

You've materialized a query out of nowhere; and reused it: query = query.Where ...

@GerrySchmitz It is not out of nowhere. It already contains filtered data from previous filters. In my case, Filter is made of a couple of filtering properties and then I handle each one of them individually.

This is sort of a guess, but I think you can try to rewrite it like this
.Where(p => searchedTerm == "" || EF.Functions.Like(something, $"%{searchedTerm}%"))

So no SQL is generated if searchterm is "", and else you have the like instead of the charindex.

This won't change anything - the server still has to scan the entire table.

That's why I have the initial condition to only run this LINQ query when the Filter.Client is not empty. Or would the change to .Like compared to the charindex generated by the .Contains change a lot?

@user27910466 nothing will change. Do you want substring search enough to pay for Azure Search or something similar and modify your code accordingly? Or is it enough to use just Any(linkage=> linkage.MainSubject.Name.StartsWith(term) || linkage.MainContact.Name.StartsWith(term)) ?

As mentioned doing a "like" forces the database to scan, also the if statement complicates the query plan solution further
Can you rather select the data and do the contains on the app side?
var linkageData = query
    .SelectMany(p => p.AddressBookLinkage)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(linkage => new 
    {
        MainContactId = linkage.MainContactId,
        Name = linkage.MainContactId == null ? linkage.MainSubject.Name : linkage.MainContact.Name
    })
    .ToList();

var result = linkageData
    .Where(linkage => linkage.Name.Contains(searchedTerm))
    .ToList();

